# Declare and allocate memory for an array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, structure

I'm trying to declare and allocate memory for an array of structures defined as follows:

```
typedef struct y{
int count;
char *word;
} hstruct
```

What I have right now is:

```
hstruct *final_list;
final_list = calloc (MAX_STR, sizeof(hstruct));
```

`MAX_STR`being the max size of the `char word` selector.
I plan on being able to refer to the it as:
`final_list[i].count`, which would be an integer and
`final_list[i].word`, which would be a string.

`i`being an integer variable.

However, such expressions always return `(null)`. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you initializing the counts or words anywhere?

Comment: You are confused about how calloc works. The first argument should be the number of elements u will have in the hstruct array.

Answer (score 1):

A struct that contains a pointer doesn't directly holds the data, but holds a pointer to the data. The memory for the pointer itself is correctly allocated through your `calloc` but it is just an address.

This means that is your duty to allocate it:

```
hstruct *final_list;
final_list = calloc(LIST_LENGTH, sizeof(hstruct));

for (int i = 0; i < LIST_LENGTH; ++i)
  final_list[i].word = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
```

This requires also to free the memory pointed by `final_list[i].word` before releasing the array of struct itself.